# How to change the colormap in quiver?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, vector

I have made this quiver plot with pgfplots:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\begin{document}
    \def\modulus{sqrt(x^2+y^2)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin = -4, xmax = 4,
            ymin = -4, ymax = 4,
            zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
            axis equal image,
            xtick distance = 1,
            ytick distance = 1,
            view = {0}{90},
            scale = 1.5,
            colorbar
        ]
            \addplot3[
                point meta = {\modulus},
                quiver = {
                    u = {-y/\modulus},
                    v = {x/\modulus},
                    scale arrows = 0.25,
                },
                quiver/colored = {mapped color},
                samples = 20,
                - stealth,
                domain = -4:4,
                domain y = -4:4,
            ] {0};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Quiver Plot]

I would like to change the colormap to greenyellow, hot, violet or any other colormap.

Comment: You can define your own color map colors using `\pgfplotsset{colormap=...}` as describen on page 193 of the `pgfplots` manual.

Comment: Sure, but how do you implement it in quiver options. I'm not sure how to use `quiver/colored = {mapped color}` and specify the colormap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of `\pgfplotsset{colormap=...}` you can define your own color map colors. `\pgfplotsset{colormap={CM}{rgb255(1)=(4,50,4) color(5)=(yellow)}}` will for example give a dark green to yellow gradient:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}


\pgfplotsset{colormap={CM}{rgb255(1)=(4,50,4) color(5)=(yellow)}}

\begin{document}
    \def\modulus{sqrt(x^2+y^2)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin = -4, xmax = 4,
            ymin = -4, ymax = 4,
            zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
            axis equal image,
            xtick distance = 1,
            ytick distance = 1,
            view = {0}{90},
            scale = 1.5,
            colorbar
        ]
            \addplot3[
                point meta = {\modulus},
                quiver = {
                    u = {-y/\modulus},
                    v = {x/\modulus},
                    scale arrows = 0.25,
                },
                quiver/colored = {mapped color},
                samples = 20,
                - stealth,
                domain = -4:4,
                domain y = -4:4,
            ] {0};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please note that using the above code, the new color map will be used as the default. If you want to only change the color map of a single plot, you can either use the above shown definition inside of the corrensonding `tikzpicture` or use the `colormap name` option as shown in the following exmple:

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\pgfplotsset{colormap={mymapgreen}{rgb255(1)=(4,50,4) color(5)=(yellow)}}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={mymapviolet}{rgb255(1)=(150,120,175) rgb255(5)=(81,6,60)}}


\begin{document}
    \def\modulus{sqrt(x^2+y^2)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            xmin = -4, xmax = 4,
            ymin = -4, ymax = 4,
            zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
            axis equal image,
            xtick distance = 1,
            ytick distance = 1,
            view = {0}{90},
            scale = 1.5,
            colorbar,
            colormap name ={mymapgreen} %<-------
        ]
            \addplot3[
                point meta = {\modulus},
                quiver = {
                    u = {-y/\modulus},
                    v = {x/\modulus},
                    scale arrows = 0.25,
                },
                quiver/colored = {mapped color},
                samples = 20,
                - stealth,
                domain = -4:4,
                domain y = -4:4,
            ] {0};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}



        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin = -4, xmax = 4,
            ymin = -4, ymax = 4,
            zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
            axis equal image,
            xtick distance = 1,
            ytick distance = 1,
            view = {0}{90},
            scale = 1.5,
            colorbar, 
            colormap name ={mymapviolet} %<-------
        ]
            \addplot3[
                point meta = {\modulus},
                quiver = {
                    u = {-y/\modulus},
                    v = {x/\modulus},
                    scale arrows = 0.25,
                },
                quiver/colored = {mapped color},
                samples = 20,
                - stealth,
                domain = -4:4,
                domain y = -4:4,
            ] {0};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Using `colormap name=` you can of course also chose from the following predefined color maps: `viridis`, `hot`, `hot2`, `jet`, `blackwhite`, `bluered`, `cool`, `greenyellow`, `redyellow`, and `violet`.

For more information, you mght be interested in  section "4.7  Markers, Linestyles, (Background) Colors and Colormaps" (especially in  subsection "4.7.6  Color Maps",  currently starting on page 192) of the `pgfplots` manual.